# Compatibility issues with windows 7 backup and linux partition

Tags: windows-7, linux, backup

I'd like to make use of the Windows 7 backup feature for system settings and user profiles due to some major hiccups in the past. Problem now is that my main OS is a linux install which also resides in the same PC but on a different hdd, and is therefore found by the windows disk manager.
The linux hdd has a /boot-partition which is marked as bootable and also contains the grub2 instance I use as boot manager and windows backup tries to include it in its routine and fails due to a unreadable file system.
I tried installing ext2 ifs to fix the unreadable part but its seems like the backup manager runs on a different level and is not wary of the driver.

Is there any option for the backup tool to completely ignore the other hdd or can I deactivate it completely for windows as I dont need access to it?

*edit*
I'm trying to backup the system images not the actual partitions.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When you configure your backup, you can check and/or uncheck disks in which you wish to back up. You may want to uncheck the linux partitions

Comment: My problem is that the line on the bottom there "Include a system image of drives: System Reserved, (C:)" also includes the linux drive and I can't remove it. I'm trying to backup the system image not the actual partitions. I should have clarified that.

Comment: Gotcha. Have you looked into anything like Acronis True Image (http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/)

Comment: Couldn't you just relabel the drives?

Comment: @kobaltz I'd rather use the internal backup system and not make a big fuzz of it. backup software exists in abundance for free. Its just that the windows install contains no critical data I just wanted to backup the windows settings etc for when it gets trashed again.

Comment: @Rob I can't change any property on the drive from within windows. No disabling or excluding. And of course I cannot label the partitions because windows can't read them at all. ext2 ifs seems to integrate into the windows explorer and not the kernel.